# Trouble with GNOME in 16.04 LTS

Tags: partitioning, gnome, 16.04

I just installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS on a laptop. I had thought that using Gnome in this version would be pretty much as in 12.04. However, it's a whole different interface. I am trying to display the menu bar permanently and move it to the bottom; I can't figure out to minimize windows, etc.

When I installed 16.04, it was to an existing system, using 10.04. I choose the "Something Else" selection to partition the drive. I left the existing /home as it is (unformatted) and set-up the / and /swap files from before, and had them formatted.. Now, it set up a different /home and the existing one is seen as a "volume" instead of the actual /home partition.

Any help out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any UNIX based OS cannot have two different home directories. The problem would have been solved if you had chosen the same home directory for the new version. You didn't have to format that way too.

To move the launcher from left to bottom type in terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom
```

To enable windows minimize on click type in terminal:

```
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ launcher-minimize-window true
```

If you encounter any error type in terminal:

```
apt install gsettings
```

and then repeat the above two commands again.

Have a nice experience with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. (I wasn't able to respond quickly due to medical circumstances.) Thanks, I understand about the /home  directory. I hadn't done that in the past. Thanks for the other tips. (I was able to install Ubuntu MATE on my wife's laptop as she is more used to that. I'll install the new Gnome package on my system.) Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, it would be nice if you give me upvote and accept my answer. Again thanks in advance.